# Organizing, encrypting, compressing external assets and loading them on runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5

Ok, I'm not sure if the topic was clear enough. I'm making a Flash based single player game. It is an executable (AIR app), to be installed and ran directly, not to be played on a browser. So, I have tons of images, videos and stuff and recently I started to load them externally using the Loader class. Published AIR installer don't mind about external stuff though, so I copy them manually after installation. This is probably wrong from the beginning, but I don't know how to incorporate them. I'll maybe figure it out later somehow, this is not the main issue but if you answer this I'll be double thankful.

Anyway, the real question is, I don't want players to see images and videos used in the game stored in resource folders. Is there a way I can make them encrypted or hidden in some package-like file (like .DAT files in many grand games)? So they cannot be accessed or messed up with, by common players. And of course, still I should be able to load them in runtime.

I looked up to this .SWC format. But, I don't think it's what I'm looking for. Anyone could easily import that file to a Flash project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Embed] Metatags even in Flash. If you don't want to pull in some small classes from the Flex SDK, there are several techniques you can use, such as what you see here http://nascode.com/2010/02/01/embedding-asset-at-compile-time-in-pure-as3-project/.

Note that assets embedded this way have to be embedded on frame N (depending on you fla/xfl settings). You can't amortize their load over the life of your swf.

Answer (score 0):

You could put small assets into your app with [Embed]. But for large assets, I would use zip files with encrypted assets. (Not encrypted zips, because they will take a lot memory to decrypt, but encrypted individual files.) I have used **airxzip** for zipping (supports processing of individual files in archives) and **as3crypto** as about the only crypto library in ActionScript. Use symmetrical algorithm like RC4, it's fast enough (10-20 MB decrypted in second.)
You'll need a key to encrypt assets. It can be hardcoded into app or decoded from serial number, if you use them for activation.
Also, archives can be named .DAT or somehow even more cryptic to scare off WinZip users :)